# How to group all conversations in a database by date, conversation thread

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got a sqllite database that has a log of received and sent messages.

```
id    sender   to   msg                    timestamp
1     2        9    1-1                    201
2     9        2    1-2                    202
3     1        9    2-1                    203
4     9        2    1-3                    204
5     9        1    2-2                    205
```

I can order them all by the timestamp, but when conversations overlap like the example above (between 9, 2, and 1) it kills readability.

How do I get it to show them by conversation?

ie:

```
id    sender   to   msg                    timestamp
1     2        9    1-1                    201
2     9        2    1-2                    202
4     9        2    1-3                    204
3     1        9    2-1                    203
5     9        1    2-2                    205
```

In my database all conversations are between 9 and another number, so for example 2 and 1 would never have a conversation.

I've input the data into [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/3b94a/3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the conversations in the order they *started*, you'll need to self join the table to get the minimum timestamp per conversation, and then just order by primarily that minimum id to get the conversations in order and secondarily the timestamp of the message to get the messages in order.

```
SELECT a.id, a.sender, a."to", a.msg, a.timestamp
FROM table1 a
JOIN table1 b
  ON CASE WHEN a.sender=9 THEN a."to" ELSE a.sender END =
     CASE WHEN b.sender=9 THEN b."to" ELSE b.sender END 
GROUP BY a.id, a.sender, a."to", a.msg, a.timestamp
ORDER BY MIN(b.timestamp), a.timestamp
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/8e25d/2).

Comment: Actually, numbering the users like that was misleading on my part.  All users actually have random/unique 12 digit numbers as identifiers.

Comment: @Chevron Updated with a query where you can use any id without caring about it being the lowest id.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected - returns all messages ordered by user, then timestamp but doesn't merge them into conversations (all messages from 100 are somewhere in the middle).

Comment: IE order returned  is `ID: 1, 4, 5, 2, 3` and `SENDER: 100, 100, 100, 101, 105` instead of desired `ID: 1, 2, 4, 3, 5` and `SENDER: 100, 101,  100, 105, 100` as per my example.

Comment: @Chevron Did you check the sqlfiddle? It returns 1,2,4,3,5 just as your sample. The reason the senders didn't match is that you updated your sample data after I wrote my answer, so updated the fiddle to match your update and can't see anything wrong.

Comment: OK, fiddle does return as it should per my example ... so I'm going to assume I screwed up my sample... let me post some better data....  I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Strangely enough, removing the "id" at the end makes the conversations return 'threaded', but the individual threads aren't ordered by timestamp

Comment: @Chevron Ah, I suspect you found the error, the "id" at the end should be "timestamp". In your sample data, they're in the same order so it returned the correct result anyway.

Comment: This still doesn't order the conversations by timestamp first, then thread.  I can't post actual data for privacy reasons or I would.

Comment: @Chevron Sadly, without a sample of data that doesn't sort correctly, there's not much I can do to correct the query.

Comment: I've updated the data with an example that improperly sorts like my data is.  It's in [sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/3b94a/3)

Comment: @Chevron Updated the answer using your latest sample data/desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this query should sort it like you want:

```
select * from 'mytable'
  ORDER by timestamp asc,
  CASE WHEN "sender"="101"
  THEN "to"
  ELSE "sender" END
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't do it ... It looked like it for the first few pages of results but that's because the conversations didn't overlap in the database.  Sorry for the accept/unaccept.